# Socket connection using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, vb.net, sockets, port

I have a VB.NET application that successfully sends a string to the specified IP address and port.

```
Public Sub BroadcastData(ByVal toSend As String, ByVal PortToSendTo As Long)
    Dim s As New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp)
    Dim sendBUF As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(toSend)
    Dim ep As New IPEndPoint(MainForm.IPToBroadcastTo, PortToSendTo)
    s.SendTo(sendBUF, ep)
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s.SendTo(sendBUF, ep))
End Sub
```

The `IPToBroadcstTo` is the IPaddress of a remote computer on the local network.

On this remote computer I can receive this string and do what I want with it using VB.NET.

I would to receive the string in Excel and write it to a cell.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is VB.NET. Excel uses VBA which although it shares some common syntax is a completely different language with a reduced set of libraries.

For example there is no `Socket` or `IPEndPoint` class in VBA.

So in short the answer is that you can't use that code to open a socket in Excel.

Have a look at the [Winsock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733709%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) control or

Maybe you could write a .NET assembly and expose it through [COM interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kew41ycz.aspx) to allow this to be used in Excel.